# getting link of an API : openweathermap.com

Tags: android, json

I am a beginner, just made few simple apps in android sdk.
I learnt about extracting data of websites which have JSON format. i tried to extract data of "openweathermap.com" for the city London by API calls in execute method of AsynkTask, and my app got crashed by getting null result from web.

Though it is giving desired result when i am passing other links like http://openweathermap.org/current to get full web Contents.

here is my code, its working.

```
 DownloadContentTask task = new DownloadContentTask();
    task.execute("http://openweathermap.org/current");
```

its not working:

```
 DownloadContentTask task = new DownloadContentTask();
    task.execute("api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London");
```

when I googled, i got

"*You can call by city name or city name and country code. API responds with a list of results that match a searching word.
Examples of API calls:*

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London"

can someone please help to get me an appropriate way for API calls. I will be Thankful.

Comment: Have you at least seen/read this page: http://openweathermap.com/appid#get

Comment: I don't know the implementation details of your DownloadContentTask, but you use http:// in the working link and don't use it in the failing one. Are you sure you didn't forget to include the http:// in your second code snippet? Other than that, it seems you have to have an API key to use the API.

Comment: yes, i included http:// but API key was missing, now i got it. thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this [API Error](http://openweathermap.org/faq#error401).You are fetching second error 401.So create an account here [Create account](https://home.openweathermap.org/users/sign_up).After sign in the account find `API Keys`.And then use like following :

`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=Your_API_Key`

Comment: Thanks @Homen, this was really helpful.

Comment: Welcome @manisha .You can accept this as answer.If you do'nt know you can check here  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow